# What in Peanut Butter dissolves glue?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

There is a common belief that *Peanut Butter* can dissolve certain types of glue. I've tested it and it does on a few common stickers. A forensic science crime procedural TV show (Bones) made a statement that

> The oils in the peanut butter will break down the cohesion of the cyanoacrylates.

The most common cyanoacrylates based glue is Super Glue, which hardens quickly.

How does Peanut Butter interact chemically with the CA glue and why? Does it make a difference when the CA has hardened or not?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: The superglue is originally the cyanoacrylates suspended in a solvent such as acetone or MEK, as the solvent evaporates after application the glue dries. The natural oils in the peanut butter or other adulterants present would act to dissolve the cyanoacrylates or possibly convert them to a different compound. If it's crunchy peanut butter the small nut pieces would act as an abrasive and speed up the process. The cohesion is referring to how the materials are bound together.

Comment: I would add to what Joel wrote to say that it may be necessary only to weaken the interface between the glue and the substrate (surface it is attached to), rather than actually react with the cyanoacrylate resin. Besides the oils in peanut butter, which can lubricate between the glue and the substrate and allow slippage, the proteins in peanut butter can act as soaps to disrupt attractive forces between polar groups on the cyanoacrylate resin and the substrate.